# Laplace transform of solution of an integral equation for non-recursive logistic map computations

Tags: recurrence-relations, functional-equations, integral-equations, chaos-theory, bifurcation

Consider the logistic map,

$x_n = r \: x_{n-1} \left( 1 - x_{n-1} \right)$

If we generalize this to a complex function $f : \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$, we get,

$f \left( z \right) = r \: f \left( z-1 \right) \left( 1- f \left( z-1 \right)\right)$

$$f \left( z \right) = r \left( f \left( z-1 \right)- \left( f \left( z-1 \right) \right)^2 \right) \: \dots \: \left( 1 \right) $$

Assume that there exists a function $u: \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{R} $, such that,

$\displaystyle{f \left( z \right) = \mathcal{L} \{ u \left( z, t \right) \} \left( s \right) = \int_0^\infty u \left( z, t\right) e^{-st} dt }$

As per integration by parts,

$$\mathcal{L} \{ u \left( z, t \right) \} \left( s \right) = \frac{1}{s} \left( u \left( z, 0 \right) + \mathcal{L} \{ \dot{u} \left( z, t \right) \} \left( s \right)\right) \: \dots \: \left( 2 \right)$$

Where $\dot{u} \left( z, t\right) = \frac{\partial u \left( z,t \right)}{\partial t}$

Notice that equations $\left( 1 \right)$ and $\left( 2 \right)$ have the same L.H.S. They are identical in form if we take,

$s = \frac{1}{r}, \\ u \left( z, 0 \right) = f \left( z-1 \right), \\ \mathcal{L} \{ \dot{u} \left( z, t \right) \} \left( s \right) = - \left( f \left( z-1 \right) \right) ^2 \text{, or,}$

$\mathcal{L} \{ \dot{u} \left( z, t \right) \} \left( s \right) = - \left( u \left( z, 0 \right) \right)^2$

Replacing $s$ with $\frac{1}{r}$,

$$ \mathcal{L} \{ \dot{u} \left( z, t \right) \} \left( \frac{1}{r} \right) = - \left( u \left( z, 0 \right) \right)^2 \dots \left( 3 \right) $$

The same equation may be rewritten in integral form,

$\displaystyle{ \left( u \left( z,0 \right) \right)^2 + \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial u \left( z,t \right)}{\partial t} e^{-\frac{t}{r}} dt = 0 }$

Applying the Leibniz integral rule,

$\displaystyle{ \left( u \left( z,0 \right) \right)^2 + \frac{d}{dt} \int_0^\infty u \left( z,t \right) e^{-\frac{t}{r}} dt = 0 }$, or,

$\displaystyle{ \left( u \left( z,0 \right) \right)^2 + \frac{d}{dt} f \left( z \right) = 0 }$

But $\frac{d}{dt} f \left( z \right) = 0$, so,

$ \left( u \left( z,0 \right) \right)^2 = 0 \implies u \left( z,0 \right) = 0 $

$$ u \left( z,0 \right) =0 \: \dots \: \left( 4 \right) $$

But something is wrong in the above derivations because according to the above result, $f \left( z-1 \right) = u \left( z,0 \right) = 0$ which yields a constant function.

This means that our assumptions in the beginning were wrong. However, is there a way to proceed with the problem (of expressing logistic maps non-recursively) along similar lines of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at the assumption $ f ( z ) = \mathcal L _ t \{ u ( z , t ) \} ( s ) $, one can see that $ s $ does not appear on the left-hand side of the equation, which means that the Laplace transform of $ u $ is assumed to be constant (when talking about a fixed $ z $). It is well-known that no such *function* exists, and you need to [generalize the notion of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_function) to find candidates for $ u $. Doing that, [it is also well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Laplace_transforms#Table) that $ u $ must be a multiple of [Dirac $ \delta $ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). More precisely, you must have $ u ( z , t ) = f ( z ) \delta ( t ) $.

The point is that generalized functions do not exactly act like functions. Dirac $ \delta $ function, for example, on one hand acts like a function that that take the value zero at any point other than the origin, but on the other hand, has positive integral; for any $ \epsilon > 0 $ you have $ \int _ { - \infty } ^ { - \epsilon } \delta ( t ) \ \mathrm d t = \int _ \epsilon ^ { + \infty } \delta ( t ) \ \mathrm d t = 0 $, while $ \int _ { - \infty } ^ { + \infty } \delta ( t ) \ \mathrm d t = 1 $. This can't happen for any genuine function, even if you allow the function to take the value $ + \infty $; considering a function $ f : ( - \infty , + \infty ) \to [ - \infty , + \infty ] $ such that $ f ( x ) = 0 $ for any $ x \in ( - \infty , 0 ) \cup ( 0 , + \infty ) $ and $ f ( 0 ) = + \infty $, you still have $ \int _ { - \infty } ^ { + \infty } f ( t ) \ \mathrm d t = 0 $, in the sense of [Lebesgue integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration).

That said, it should be obvious that you have to avoid treating $ u $ like a function that takes definite values at given points $ z $ and $ t $. As long as you're keeping a distance from $ t = 0 $ though, it acts like a constant zero function, which may explain why you ended up with $ u ( z , 0 ) = 0 $: because $ u ( z , \epsilon ) $ behaves like the constant zero function for $ \epsilon \ne 0 $, even for arbitrarily small values of $ \epsilon $. But note that this explanation is rather loose, as $ u ( z , 0 ) $ has no meaning, because Dirac $ \delta $ function has no definite value at the origin.